# Why is this abnormal behaviour in exported function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had some experience in writing node application, but having this issues in this typical JS file with code

proxy.js

```
const proxy = {
    host: '127.0.0.1'
};

exports.ProxyUrl = () => {
    return `http://${proxy.host}`;
}
```

when calling this file from another JS file

index.js

```js
const proxyUrl = require('./proxy.js');
console.log(proxyUrl);
```

it supposed to prints '127.0.0.1', but is print this in console

```
() => {
    return `http://${proxy.host}`;
}
```

this only happen in this JS file, rest of my JS file works well.

Comment: call the function? `console.log(proxyUrl());`

Answer (score 0):

The `exports` object is exactly equivalent to what a `require` from another file resolves to. So, when you assign to a `ProxyUrl` property of the object, the imported object will have a property with a `ProxyUrl` property.

If you want the export to be *just* the function, rather than an object with a property, then assign to the `module.exports`:

```
const proxy = {
    host: '127.0.0.1'
};

module.exports = () => {
    return `http://${proxy.host}`;
};
```

and then you can

```
const proxyUrl = require('./proxy.js');
console.log(proxyUrl());
```

Otherwise, with your original code, you'd have to access the `ProxyUrl` property of the `require`d object first:

```
const { ProxyUrl } = require('./proxy.js');
console.log(ProxyUrl());
```

Comment: thanks, i just realized I'd forgot add (), because this is a function

Comment: Yes, you need to call the function, but you also need to make sure what you're exporting lines up with what you're importing.